# No puedo editar php.ini

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, sqlite

Tal y como dice el titulo, tengo un problema con php artisan y en todas partes salía que la solución es editar el archivo php.ini.

Así que me encamine y finalmente encontré el dichoso archivo, pero como se ve en la siguiente imagen...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay una forma de cambiar los permisos para poder editar el archivo?

Comment: Hola @hugo. Tan pronto como abras el terminal escribe `sudo -i` te pide la credencial de superusiario, la das y abres el php.ini en el editor, tal como hiciste.
Es posible que antes de abrirlo tengas que cambiar atributos para poderlo sobreescribir usando chmod

Comment: me llama la atención qué tanto usas para tu servidor web, estoy casi seguro que el php.ini depende totalmente de cada virtualhost que tienes agreagado, es decir, siempre hay un php.ini para cada virtualhost, no uno en general, y eso lo compruebas fácilmente creando un archivo .php y escribiendo dentro de él <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> ahí podrás ver cuál es la ruta del php.ini que ocupa este virtualhost y así poder editarlo, recuerda reiniciar apache cada que lo modificas para que refresque los cambios. Recuerda que el php.ini es individual por virtualhost y normalmente existe en una carpeta etc

Answer (score 1):

Para localizar un fichero, debieras simplemente actualizar la base de datos del programa slocate con:

```
sudo updatedb
```

Luego, simplemente, pasa como parámetro el nombre del fichero a slocate:

```
sudo slocate php.ini
```

que en mi caso arroja:

```
/etc/httpd/php.ini
```

Puedes ver los permisos del fichero con ls:

```
ls -al /etc/httpd/php.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67928 ene 21 16:31 /etc/httpd/php.ini
```

Como ves, el propietario del fichero (root) tiene permisos de lectura y escritura (-rw), y el resto solo de lectura.
Como bien te han comentado ya, podrás, pues, editar el fichero bien logueándote como root (poco recomendable), o adquiriendo permisos elevados temporalmente con sudo:

```
sudo vim /etc/httpd/php.ini
```

sustituye vim por tu editor favorito, o usa vim, al gusto.
Sería conveniente que en vez de pantallazos copiases el código en tu pregunta.
Suerte.